# Remove import when using Kotlin's @Deprecated "ReplaceWith" annotation

Tags: kotlin, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I have a custom function `MutableStateFlow.update()`, which i want to deprecate in favor of the official "kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update" version.

```
@Deprecated(
    message = "This is not thread safe. Use the official version from kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update",
    ReplaceWith("update(transformation)", "kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update"),
    DeprecationLevel.ERROR
)
public inline fun <T> MutableStateFlow<T>.update(transformation: (previousValue: T) -> T) {
    value = transformation(value)
}
```

This works ok-ish:
The main issue is that the signature of the old & the new fun are the same, so the IDE gets confused which to choose, since both are imported.
I therefore need to remove the import for my old version when the `ReplaceWith` is called. Is this possible? (Is there a better alternative?)

In case it matters: We're working mainly with Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

If this is all in one open project, you could Refactor->Rename your update function (Shift + F6) to some unique name. Then there won't be the import conflict.